# sorting - Order By date ASC

Tags: mysql

I have "date" column in mysql saving the dates with this format
17-09-2014 (DD-MM-YYYY)

I need to sort them ascending, so I used this command:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date ASC
```

But I found this result:

```
17-09-2014
18-09-2015
19-09-2014
```

It should be:

```
17-09-2014
19-09-2014
18-09-2015
```

It sorts the day only ASC not the full date

Comment: The correct fix is to change this column's type from the varchar it appears to be, to a [proper `DATE/DATETIME` type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html), for which sorting will work correctly automatically.

Comment: wich datetype is your datecolumn?

Comment: These dates are not saved as mysql native data type `date` or `datetime` so you may need to convert it to real date at the time of sort using `str_to_date` function

Comment: your data type must be date and store as YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d-%m-%Y') ASC
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `STR_TO_DATE()` to convert your strings to MySQL date values and ORDER BY the result:

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(datestring, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

However, you would be wise to convert the column to the `DATE` data type instead of using strings